# Hide and Show elements by clicking on a link with Java Script without Jquery

Tags: javascript, class, hide, addition, show

I really need some help, I wanna know what's the best way to hide and show elements by clicking on a link just using Java Script without Jquery.

So, when I click on the "Link 1" need to add the "class active" and just the "`<div id="cont1">`" should be shown while the others should be hidden.

Other thing, is do this with the possibility to add more HTML Links and Content in the future, without the necessity to change the JS code.

I will be eternally grateful if someone help me!

Follow the HTML code:

```
        <div class="all">
          <ul class="links">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
           </ul>
          <div class="content">
             <div id="cont1">
                 <p>Content 1</p>
             </div>
             <div id="cont2">
                 <p>Content 2</p>
             </div>
             <div id="cont3">
                 <p>Content 3</p>
             </div>
             <div id="cont4">
                 <p>Content 4</p>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What browsers does your code need to be compatible with?

Comment: I'm trying here but I couldn't do, So I don't wana to mess your logic. Needs to be crossbrowser, mainly with Chrome, FF and IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to fix your code.

1. add missing `[0]` after `document.getElementsByClassName("content")`
2. change `getElementsByClassName()` to `querySelectorAll()` in order to work in IE8
3. change variable `i` in `navList.children[i].onclick` to remembered variable `index`
4. change variable `i` start value to `0`
5. pass `index + 1` as a dest of `mudaConteudo()` since index start with 0 but your content ids start with 1

Here the result:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function mudaConteudo(elm, dest) {
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById('cont' + dest).style.display = "block";
    }
    var navList = document.querySelectorAll(".links")[0];
    for (var i = 0, len = navList.children.length; i < len; i++) {
        (function(index){
            navList.children[index].onclick = function () {
                mudaConteudo(this, index + 1);
                document.querySelectorAll(".active")[0].removeAttribute("class");
                this.className = "active";
            };
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: The Script is broked... a lot of lines is undefined when i debug...
For example:
TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Other one:
TypeError: navList is undefined
for (var i = 0, len = navList.children.length; i < len; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var links = list[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function () {
        var target = this.innerHTML.substr(-1);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
        var subdivs = divs[0].getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < subdivs.length; i++) subdivs[i].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cont' + target).style.display = 'block';
    };
};
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rg7Em/)**