# Importing external HTML inner content with Javascript AJAX without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, import

I need some help, I've got the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu-list">
  <li class="active"><a href="cont1.html" title="Title 1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="cont2.html" title="Title 2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="cont3.html" title="Title 3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="cont4.html" title="Title 4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">           
   <div class="innerContent">
        <!-- Insert external HTML content here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

So, when I click "Link 1", for example, I need to get the inner content from "cont1.html" to be appended inside of the div class="innerContent", not forgetting to add the "class="active"" inside the clicked li. Using just Javascript/AJAX without Jquery and without changing this HTML.

I did a similar [**example here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884640/hide-and-show-elements-by-clicking-on-a-link-with-java-script-without-jquery/15935020#15935020), but is working for the content of the same page, not different pages, and I don't know why but doesn't work on IE.

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <ul class="menu-list">
   <li class="active"><a href="javascript:display('cont1.html');" title="Title 1" >Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:display('cont2.html');" title="Title 2" >Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:display('cont3.html');" title="Title 3" >Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:display('cont4.html');" title="Title 4" >Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="content">           
  <div class="innerContent" id="innerContent">
  </div>
</div>
```

javaScript

```
function display(url)
{
   var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("innerContent").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Can't change the makup HTML and use "onclick" attribute, object tag or iframe. Must use the original HTML without any changes.
Thanks for trying anyway

Comment: So you have those limitations as well ?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have. I don't know if you saw this example that I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884640/hide-and-show-elements-by-clicking-on-a-link-with-java-script-without-jquery/15935020#15935020

Comment: I saw that but you need the content from other html pages in this page. So you have two options include the content with in page and hide and un-hide then based on the link clicked OR pull the content using Ajax then display them.

Comment: That's it using AJAX... Do u know how?

Comment: Look at this example http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: Can you use innerHTML ? If yes I can create a fiddle for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28684/discussion-between-user1309015-and-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Updated the answer. Try this

Comment: what is error that you are getting ? Did you checked the path of the file that you are passing to Javascript menthod "URL" is correct.

Comment: Sorry dude, actually is working, I was doing just local test..
Many thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to make an AJAX request for the external file, then use the responseText to populate the innerHTML of your container.

This article guides you through how to make that an XMLHttpRequest -- AJAX without jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

So you'll have to create a function, which runs when you click one of those links, that will 1) perform the AJAX request to get the external HTML; 2) populate your innerContent `<div>` with the responseText; and 3) change which `<li>` is classed "active".

Comment: Good describe, but can you send me an example?