# List like container in html/javascript which is populated through csv/json

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv, listbox

I am new to web development. I am trying to create a webpage with a list-like container which lists all *.html files contained in a directory. And a mouse click on one of these listed names displays the .html in another container on the same page.

I am thinking of storing the filenames of the .html files in a csv or json file to make it easy to read through javascript and populate the list-like container.

I would really appreciate any pointers on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is very generic... Have you tried anything yet? Divide your problem into smaller ones an try to solve each one of them

Comment: Javascript wont allow you to get a directory listing you would need to use a server side script such as PHP or ASP and query that using ajax

Comment: Both of these guys are right - you've got multiple tasks you need to accomplish here.  I've tried to answer the one that is covered by the tags you've included with you question - but you'll need to probably ask another/look for more information on the directory listing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a good server side solution to read your files/csv and service the data to your front end - you could also use node as a solution - but both of those topics are outside of scope here (at the least, I'm probably not the best person to answer them, and the answers I give would lead to many more questions).

to do the front end bit - you should use jQuery, because it will simplify a lot of things for you.

if you've got your json string (probably just an array in this case) and it inflates/parses to something like this:

**Parsed JSON:**

```
files = [
  'file1.html',
  'file2.html',
  ...etc...
];
```

you can push these into an **empty, existing UL element** as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<div id="pageHTML"></div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $list = $('#list'),
        $html = $('#pageHTML');

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
       $list.append('<li><a href="/path/to/'+files[i]+'">'+files[i]+'</a></li>');
    }

    // when a link is clicked, we can load the content via ajax
    $list.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $html.load(this.href);
    });

});
```

Jquery simplifies & makes it a lot easier to read what's going on here compared with the standard javascript version linked to in @NullPointerException's answer.

XMLHTTPRequest is also are a very complicated field.  As a new developer, there are lots of potential pitfalls along the way if you decide to "roll your own" solution.  Probably a better idea to let jQuery handle the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152609/importing-external-html-inner-content-with-javascript-ajax-without-jquery)

You can read the list of HTMLs from JSON and display them as list and then follow this question to load the content in the same page